# Сколько живёт сессионная переменная?

Tags: php, сессия

Создаю переменную сессии:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['text'] = "Text";
```

Сколько времени она будет жить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Интересный и не такой простой вопрос, как многие думают.

Ответ складывается из двух составляющих:

- времени жизни куки
- времени срабатывания механизма сборки мусора, который удалит файл сессии с сервера

Оба этих пункта настраиваются, но мы сейчас будем говорить о дефолтных настройках.

- время жизни куки по умолчанию - "пока пользователь не закроет браузер". Раньше, когда в браузерах ещё не было вкладок, это имело смысл. Сейчас, когда даже если мы закрываем вкладку, но браузер все равно остается открытым, остаётся жить и сессионная кука. То есть при повторном открытии вкладки с тем же сайтом, сессия будет жива-живехонька.
- по умолчанию сборщик мусора убивает все файлы сессий, которые не обновлялись дольше 1440 секунд, или 24 минуты. Но это тоже не точно, поскольку сборщик мсора запускается не при каждом запросе, а с некоторой вероятностью. И на не очень посещаемом сайте старый файл сессии может валяться часами.

Answer (score 1):

Смотри значение в php.ini `session.gc_maxlifetime`

Comment: Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, это где?

Answer (score 0):

Переменная сессии существует до тех пор пока существует сессия, в которой она создана.

Время жизни сессии можно задать в коде на PHP:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 10800); //30 минут
```

В конфигурационном файле php.ini:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 10800
session.cookie_lifetime = 10800
```

Или в файле .htaccess:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10800
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 10800
```

Источник: [PHP — работа с сессиями](http://lifeexample.ru/php-primeryi-skriptov/php-rabota-s-sessiyami.html).

Обычно по умолчанию сессия живёт 20 минут (если не ошибаюсь).